# Inserting Identity values from dataset into table using table adapter VB.net

Tags: vb.net, adapter, identity

Is there any way to get the table adapter to insert the values already in the dataset I pass it when inserting new rows?

I am synchronising two databases and this would be useful.

Here is currently how I am trying to do it but it auto increments and creates new identity values.

```
    Dim dAdapterConstraints As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + Tablename, _oConn)
    Dim builder As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(dAdapterConstraints)
    builder.QuotePrefix = "["
    builder.QuoteSuffix = "]"
    dAdapterConstraints.InsertCommand = builder.GetInsertCommand
    Dim insertcommandstr As String = dAdapterConstraints.InsertCommand.CommandText.Substring(0, dAdapterConstraints.InsertCommand.CommandText.IndexOf("(") + 1) + " [" + Primarykey + "], " + dAdapterConstraints.InsertCommand.CommandText.Substring(dAdapterConstraints.InsertCommand.CommandText.IndexOf("(") + 1, dAdapterConstraints.InsertCommand.CommandText.Length - (dAdapterConstraints.InsertCommand.CommandText.IndexOf("(") + 1))
    insertcommandstr = insertcommandstr.Replace("@p1", "@po1, @p1")
    dAdapterConstraints.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@po1", getdbtype(dataset.Tables(0).Columns(Primarykey).DataType), dataset.Tables(0).Columns(Primarykey).MaxLength, Primarykey)
    insertcommandstr = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT [" + Tablename + "] ON " + insertcommandstr + " SET IDENTITY_INSERT [" + Tablename + "] OFF"
    dAdapterConstraints.InsertCommand.CommandText = insertcommandstr
    dataset.EnforceConstraints = False

    ' opens connection 
    'fills dataset with results
    Try
        For Each row As DataRow In dataset.Tables(0).Rows
            row.SetAdded()
        Next
        dAdapterConstraints.Update(dataset)
    Catch ex As Exception
        _oConn.Close()
        MsgBox("Could not execute query on server database," + ex.ToString + ";Updating and inserting")
        Return False
    End Try
```

Comment: Have you considered using SqlBulkCopy instead? If you do then you can use the SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity to retain the identity column

Comment: If I use this method will if update rows that are already there?

Comment: No. You would have to update those separately. If it were me I would SqlBulkCopy all those rows up into a #TEMP table and then synchronise via SQL.